# Is there a way to determine if an inputstream is readOnly?

Tags: java, inputstream

I was thinking something like a

`File file =new File(inputStream) // not possible though. file.canWrite`,

but i cant seem to find a solution to convert input stream into a file without writing it elsewhere. Thank you!

Comment: You look to have things backwards. Wouldn't you do `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("someFile.foo"));`?

Comment: Or better -- wrap it all in a BufferedInputStream

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have it backwards.

By definition, an `InputStream` will only ever allow you to read a stream of bytes, wherever that stream of bytes comes from. It may be from a file, or a network socket, or a custom provider. By its very definition, you can only read from an `InputStream` anyway.

Since you seem to be working with files here, you can check whether a file is read only *for the user running the current process* using:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/my/file");

// is it writable? If no, consider "read only"
final boolean canWrite = Files.isWritable(path);
```

And to open an `InputStream` from a `Path`, use:

```
try (
    final InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path);
) {
    // work with "in"
}
```

Comment: Hi fge, Thank you for your response. I appreciate it. Currently my method receives a DataHandler object which represents a file content. I was thinking of a way to determine if the content file in the data handler is readOnly.

Comment: @WayneDeLosAngeles: again that's backwards thinking. You make it read only by only reading from it, and not writing to it.

Comment: @WayneDeLosAngeles how do you know that this particular `DataHandler` represents the contents of a file? Is that an API of yours? Another API? Is it forced to have a file as a "backend" to provide an `InputStream`? And, perhaps more importantly, why do you care in the first place?